# Memory management for gauss elimination

Tags: c, memory-management, mpi, numerical-methods

A matrix is created in processor 0 and scattered to other processors. A matrix is a symmetric dense matrix. That's why it is initialized in processor 0.

A matrix is created in this way:

```
A=malloc(sizeof(double)*N*N);
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    for(j=0; j<N; j++)
     A(i,j)=rand()%10; // The code will be changed.
```

A(i,j) is defined as:

```
#define A(i,j) A[i*N+j]
```

and N has to be 100,000 to test the algorithm.

The problem here is: if N=100,000 then the memory needed is approximately 76GB. What do you suggest to store the A matrix?

PS: Algorithm works very well when N<20.000 and the cluster is a distrubed memory system(2GB RAM per processor)

Comment: Why don't you have each node generate its own section of the data?

Comment: Because i need to test the algorithm for 1 processor to see the speed-up

Comment: Ah, ok.  Then all the stuff about scattering, etc. is a bit of a red herring?

Comment: You may be right about it but if there is 2GB per processor and we need approximately 76GB memory then don't we need at least 33 processors to run it? And i need to edit the question because A matrix should be dense symmetric matrix that's why i create A matrix in processor 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this, as stated in comments, to do a scaling test, then Oli Charlesworth is completely right; anything you do is going to make this an apples-to-oranges comparison, because your node doesn't have 76GB to use.   Which is fine; one of the big reasons to use MPI is to tackle problems that couldn't fit on one node.  But by trying to shoehorn 76GB of data onto one processor, the comparison you're doing isn't going to make any sense.   As mentioned by both Oli Charlesworth and caf, through various methods you can use disk instead of RAM, but then your 1 processor answer is going not going to be directly comparable to the fits-in-RAM numbers you get from larger number of nodes, so you're going to be going to a lot of work to get a number which won't actually mean anything.

If you want scaling results on this sort of problem, you either start with the lowest number of nodes that the problem *does* fit on, and take data at increasing numbers of processors, or you do [weak scaling](https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/index.php/Introduction_To_Performance#Weak_Scaling_Tests), rather than [strong scaling](https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/index.php/Introduction_To_Performance#Strong_Scaling_Tests) tests -- you keep the work-per-processor constant while scaling up the number of processors, rather than the total work being constant.

Incidentally, however you do the measurements, you'll end up with better results if, as Oli Charlesworth suggests, you have each procesor generate its own data rather than have a serial bottleneck by having rank 0 do the generation of the matrix and then have all the processors receive their parts.

Comment: and @Oli Charlesworth, you all are right about apples-to-oranges comparison. I told the proffessor, who gave this project, about the scale problem and he told me the exactly the same thing as you said. I thought that he want me to implement a file based memory mapping but i was wrong. Btw, about the generation of matrix on processor 0, i am trying to create a symmetric dense matrix that's why i insisted on this way. An advice about generation of symmetric matrix will be useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are programming on a POSIX system with sufficient virtual address space (which in practice will mean a 64 bit system), you can use `mmap()`.

Either create an anonymous mapping of the required size (this will be swap-backed, which will mean you'll need at least 76GB of swap), or create a real file of the required size and map that.

The file-backed solution has the advantage that if your cluster has a shared file system, you don't need to explicitly transfer the matrix to each processor - you can simply `msync()` it after creating it, and then map the right region on each processor.

Answer (score 1):

*If* you can switch to C++, you might look into [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/), which is an STL implementation specifically designed for huge datasets, with transparent disk-backed support, etc.

Comment: Probably i can't switch to C++ but if it is the best way to do it then i will try.

Comment: @Onatm: Obviously, a disk-backed memory will be much, much slower than if you had 76GB of physical RAM at your disposal.  I'm not sure there's a way to do a direct speedup comparison, because you can't create a representative 1-core version.  Apples and oranges, etc.